# How to convert the yaml file into a array using java

Tags: java, parsing, yaml, snakeyaml, jyaml

i need to access the yaml file data into the java file.
i used the YamlReader class and now the yaml file is loaded into the java class object.
now all the information is in object and i want to extract it from this object.How can i do this .
Can any one help me please i am stuck with this problem.

Comment: whats the actual problem here? converting data to array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read into a Map:

```
YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader("contact.yml"));
Object object = reader.read();
System.out.println(object);
Map map = (Map)object;
System.out.println(map.get("address"));
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/yamlbeans/

Answer (score 0):

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
String document = "\n- Hesperiidae\n- Papilionidae\n- Apatelodidae\n- Epiplemidae";
List<String> list = (List<String>) yaml.load(document);
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using snakeyaml, the code below didn't work for me. When the yaml object returned my object, it returned a `LinkedHashMap` type. So I cast my returned object into a `LinkedHashMap`.

```
public class YamlConfig {

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    String path = "blah blah";
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(this.path));
    LinkedHashMap<String,String> map;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void loadHashMap() throws IOException {
        Object data = yaml.load(input);// load the yaml document into a java object
         this.map = (LinkedHashMap<String,String>)data;
         System.out.println(map.entrySet()); //use this to look at your hashmap keys
         System.out.println(map);//see the entire map
    }
```